# showing hatchstyles in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to set the background to a hatchstyle but don't know how to access System.Drawing.Drawing2D in javascript. The table is created by javascript. Example of table below.

```
<table style="background:hatchstyle.cross>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: asp.net and javascript are nowhere related.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access ASP.NET members in Javascript.  You would have to define your own CSS values for a hatch style in order to do this with Javascript.